# Remove specific number of FragmentTransactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets say I have this flow in my app. A user enters Fragment1, then he goes on to frag2, then frag3. In frag3 he decides to enter another view (frag4) that will eventually bring him back to frag3.
He enters frag5, and then he gets back to frag3. If the user in this situation presses the back button, I want him to go back to frag2. How can I achieve this behavior? All the `FragmentTransactions` are saved in the backstack up until this point.

I was thinking of maybe removing frag4 and frag5 by doing:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = new FragmentTransaction(getSupportFragmentManager());
ft.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag4"));
ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag5"));
ft.commit();
```

But this didn't work out. I want it to directly go back to Frag2.

```
                        -> Frag4
                       /         \
Frag1 -> Frag2 -> Frag3 <-Frag5<--

                   / \
                    |
                    |
Here I want to go back to Frag2 after I have visited Frag4 and Frag5
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(int, int)

Comment: @Karakuri Already been looking through it. Can't really say that documentation answers my question